# Json string to Array (js, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following string in my jquery function:

```
{"rows":[{"id_sala":"27","horas":"4","Fecha":"2014-05-05"},{"id_sala":"27","horas":"5","Fecha":"2015-04-30"}]}
```

and I need to convert this into an array for use it in google charts, i have tried to program my own function but I had a really bad headhache.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the function `JSON.parse()` and then you'll need to iterate over it with loops.

Comment: $.parseJSON( jsonString ) 
if you have the JSON string in jQuery

JSON.parse( jsonString ) 
if you have the JSON string in a browser

Comment: @evolutionxbox @detheridge02 that was my first option, but when I pass the resulting arr to the google method it sais `Uncaught Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array`

Comment: Could you add your google charts init please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing of the `jsonString` gives you a `json` object like this. `Object {rows: Array[2]}`. Since you need an array of rows to be passed to the `addRows` method, you have to code as shown below.

```
String jsonString ='{"rows":[{"id_sala":"27","horas":"4","Fecha":"2014-05-05"},{"id_sala":"27","horas":"5","Fecha":"2015-04-30"}]}';
var rows=  JSON.parse(jsonString).rows; //Returns an array of rows
//Pass rows to the addRows method.
```

Comment: Dunno why but this worked... thx man u rly saved me from a hard job